# Update a dataframe based on values from other. It is a traditional UPSERT task with a new indicator column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do an UPSERT task over two dataframes.

[image]

Here I am updating df2 with df1.

I have used something like this:

```
final_df=df1.set_index('EmpID').combine_first(df2.set_index('EmpID'))
final_df.reset_index()
```

My result here is:

```
   EmpID    Name    Salary  Status
0   A       John    1000.0  Left
1   B       Mary    2000.0  Working
2   C       Samie   3000.0  Left
3   D        Doe    4000.0  NaN
4   E       Lance   2500.0  Contractor
```

Also I am not able to add the 'Indicator' column

Comment: In your example, Marie has a different name between the first and second dataframe. Is that part of the example?

Comment: Yes NickODell and even "Sam" has different name. This can be considered as a name change. Basically the index can be "EmpID" rest everything remains same

Answer (score 1):

I did this and almost achieved my goal, but is there any better way? plus what to do with the column insert?

```
df=pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2.EmpID.isin(df1.EmpID)]])
df=df.set_index('EmpID').join(df2.set_index('EmpID'),how='outer',rsuffix='_R')
df[['Name','Salary','Status_R']].reset_index()

    EmpID   Name    Salary  Status_R
0   A       John    1000.0  Left
1   B       Mary    2000.0  Working
2   C       Samie    NaN    Left
3   D       Doe     4000.0  NaN
4   E       Lance   2500.0  Contractor
```